# Passing a parameter in Twilio Studio using REST API and set it as a variable

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to pass a parameter in Twilio Studio but I don't know how to set it as a variable in order to pass it back using the HTTP Request.

As an example :
I have my URL demo.com/id=123

How to map the id as a variable in order to send the ID back to a webhook based on other Studio Flow statuses, using the HTTP Request widget.

I've tried searching for this but I couldn't find any help on this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> As an example : I have my URL demo.com/id=123

That url doesn't seem valid - it is missing the ? mark - and as-is wouldn't pass the variable to your controller/api endpoint.

Try http://demo.com?id=123

Or, http://demo.com/123 as that is also valid.

Your demo.com should receive the 123 either as a query parameter (when using id=123) or as a route parameter (when using /123).

To actually use a variable, use the {{curlybraces}} syntax from the [Liquid Templating language](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/get-started#liquid-template-language) such as {{widgets.first_question.inbound.Body}}

A third option, is to use the Request Body or the HTTP Parameters of the [HTTP Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request#optional-configuration-for-make-http-request-widget)

```
Request Body
Text to include in the body of your request 
{{widgets.first_question.inbound.Body}}
```

and

```
 HTTP Parameters    
 Key/Value pairs representing URL parameters to pass along with the request, 
 as string literals or variables.

 "key": "value" or key: {{widgets.first_question.inbound.Body}}
```